# How to increase the accuracy of optimal point obtained by ADMM?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming

What is the best algorithm to polish the optimal point obtained by the ADMM method for a constrained quadratic program?

I've already studied the primal-dual method. Although it can obtain a solution of high accuracy in a reasonable number of iterations, it is not sensitive to the starting point. So while I'm using a point that is too close to the optimal point to warm-start the PD algorithm, it seems as if an arbitrary point is being used. Can you suggest another algorithm in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the contrary, warm starting primal-dual interior point methods can actually cause the method to converge more slowly than starting with a well centered initial solution.  The reason is that your near-optimal solution is likely to be very close to the edge of the feasible reason and not well centered.

Conventional active set methods for QP don't have this problem and could be used to refine your ADMM solution.

Comment: Great, Thank you so much.

Comment: I have found a Ph.D. thesis [here](https://escholarship.org/uc/item/2sp3173p),  it has considered general inequality constrained quadratic problems, but I'm dealing with inequality constrained convex quadratics, Do you know any article that is more specific? unfortunately, I couldn't find anything other than the box constrained convex quadratic problems(In my case the inequality are of the form $Dx + E <= 0$.

Comment: A selection of software packages for convex QP's can be found at http://plato.asu.edu/sub/nlores.html#QP-problem

Comment: Thanks again, I checked them out and all of them were either box constrained or some other form of quadratic problems, would you please suggest an article or something that has covered linear inequality/equality constrained quadratic problem?

Comment: quadprog implements the Goldfarb-Idnani dual algorithm for inequality constrained problems (and can handle equality constraints by reformulating them as a pair of inequality constraints.)

Comment: Thanks to you, I've found algorithms for both general quadratic and strictly convex quadratic problems, however, I'm going to use it for convex quadratics(not necessarily strictly convex), is it better to use the method for the general case or to ignore (nonstrict) convex ones and use the Goldfarb-Idnani dual algorithm?

Comment: Any QP solve that can handle non-convex quadratic objectives (finding a local minimum) can also be used to solve problems that are convex.  As a practical matter, it's hard to determine whether your quadratic objective is indefinite or semidefinite- you'd need to apply some kind of tolerance in a test.

Comment: one last question, the initial point for the active set method must satisfy the equality constrained $Ax + b =0 $, but $ Ax_0 + b $ in which $x_0$ is the obtained solution by the ADMM is only close to zero, how should I handle this?

Comment: You could simply solve an equation $A \Delta x=-b-Ax_{0}$ and perturb the solution to satisfy the equation constraints.

Comment: I have implemented this approach, but I've surprisingly noticed that the number of iterations that Active-Set method needs to reach the optimum point whilst using ADMM to warm start equals to using $ x_0 = A / b $ as the initial point. What should I do about this?

Comment: You haven't discussed your constraints in detail- do you have upper and lower bounds on variables, linear inequalities, linear equations, or what?  For bounds constraints, if a component of the ADMM solution is close to its upper/lower bound, then you should initialize that constraint in the active set.  e.g. if $x_{1}$ is 1.0e-6 in your ADMM solution and the lower bound on this variable is 0, then you probably want to put that lower bound in the active set and round the variable down to 0.  If you don't do this well, then it will take many active set iterations to get the active set right.

Comment: I'm dealing with linear inequalities of the form $ D x + E <= 0 $, what should I do in this case? ( and I have to mention that the matrix $D$ is not necessarily sparse).

Comment: You'll need to determine which of these inequalities are "tight" at the ADMM optimal solution up to some reasonable tolerance, and then put those into the active set before you start the active set method.  e.g. if y=Dx+E, and $y_{1}=-1.0e-6$, then you should treat the first constraint as active.

Comment: If your ADMM solution is good enough to identify the set of active constraints for the optimal solution then the active set method should run in one iteration.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider this point.

Comment: sometimes the solution cannot predict the active constraints well, I guess ill-scaled matrices cause this.

Comment: The solution obtained by the ADMM cannot predict the active inequality constraints, although it is too close to the optimal solution ( I have checked the solution using some well-known solvers), can you suggest a method other than the Active-Set method for polishing, because it seems as if it is not efficient enough in this case.

Comment: If constraint $i$ is active at optimality, than $E_{i}$ should be close to 0 in your ADMM solution.  If it isn't close to 0 than your ADMM solution isn't actually close to optimality.  So, what is a typical value of $E_{i}$ in the ADMM solution for a constraint $i$ that is tight in the optimal solution?

Comment: Actually, sometimes it is not close to zero at all, it depends on the scale of the matrices(if the coefficients are large it may be around $-10$), but when I compute the $norm(x - x_{opt})$ it is around $0.01$ for large n like $ 1000$.

Comment: It simply doesn't make sense to have $\| x^{*} - x_{0} \| = 0.01$ when a component of $x_{0}$ is more than 10 away from its optimal value, unless of course you don't have a unique optimal solution.

Comment: I randomly converted the problem to $x = x / 10$ , and now it can compute the active sets, it seems as if the scale of matrices play a great role here, first I used the preconditioning method in the article "An Operator Splitting Solver for
Quadratic Programs" but it didn't help, do you know how should I scale the coefficient matrices to get the best results?

Comment: I didn't mean one of the components of $x$ is more than $10$ away from the optimal value, I meant some components of $Dx + E$ which are active in the optimal value get far away from zero.

Comment: In the previous comment I meant that I used change of variables.

Comment: Is barrier method a good algorithm for polishing?or it cannot be warm started just like primal dual interior point?

Comment: The primal-dual interior point method is a barrier method.  There are one-sided primal barrier methods and one sided dual barrier methods, but these would have the same problems with warm starting as the primal-dual interior point methods.